# How to post this type of Json data using Volley

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

I am using [volley](/questions/tagged/volley) to post [json](/questions/tagged/json) data to server.The data is in this form.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "user": {
                "first_name": "abc",
                "last_name": "xyz",
                "username": "abc@gmail.com",
                "email": "abc@gmail.com",
                "groups": [],
                "is_active": true
            },
            "phone": "1234567890",
            "address": "address"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to post this data using Volley ?

Answer (score 2):

jsonObject is your object that you want to pass

```
JSONObject  jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("count",ObjectList.size());
            jsonObject.put("next","");
            jsonObject.put("previous","");
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();

                JSONObject jsonObjectUser=new JSONObject();
                jsonObjectUser.put("first_name",first_name);
                jsonObjectUser.put("last_name",last_name);
                jsonObjectUser.put("username",username);
                jsonObjectUser.put("email",email);

                JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject();
                jsonObject1.put("user",jsonObjectUser);
                jsonObject1.put("address",address);
                jsonObject1.put("phone",phone);

                jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);



            jsonObject.put("results",jsonArray);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



 JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new jsonObject,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       //Process os success response
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
               }
           });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
```

Comment: Can u please help me to parse that Json data

Comment: updated the answer,if you have user list then replace ObjectList with your list

Comment: What is Object List and User

Comment: how you stored first_name,last_name and all this details?where it comes from?

Comment: I am accepting it from user using Edittext fields

Comment: updated please check it,just remove for loop if you want to pass single entry for user

Comment: I have tried but it is saying cannot resolve constructor.How to solve this

Comment: update the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Please check my below answers which helps you to solved your problem:

```
JSONObject jsonObject  = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("name", "abc");
jsonObject.put("email", "abc@gmail.com");

JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<your_data.size();i++){
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("filterId",filter_items.get(i));
        obj.put("typeName","CAT_ID");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    array.put(obj);
}
```

And finally add json array as below

```
jsonObject.put("filter",array);


JsonObjectRequest request_json = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new jsonObject,
           new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                   try {
                       //Process os success response
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
               }
           });

    // add the request object to the queue to be executed
    ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request_json);
```

Please check above and put your data into as a key and value, I am using my data as a request parameter.